# building a shared object library: ldd does not show specified name

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, shared-objects, ldd

I'm trying to build a shared object library on Debian

```
cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
```

I build the library and object as normal (`wrap.c` serves as a wrapper to create all object files)

```
gcc -c -fPIC -W -Wall -O2 -funroll-loops wrap.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so *.o
mv libtest.so /usr/local/lib/ && mv test-header.h /usr/local/include/
```

I then create a `test.c` to pull in the library and compile successfully as follows:

`gcc test.c -ltest`

However, running the program `./a.out` returns the following error:

> ./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Inspecting the `.so`, I see:

```
$ ldd /path/to/libtest.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdb71c5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1c22fba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1c23560000)
```

I don't even see `libtest.so => none`, which at least would tell me it can't find the library.

I'm not really sure what's going on here.

I am to successfully create a `.dylib` on `macOS` with the same process (with `gcc -dynamiclib -o libtest.dylib *.o`), and I can successfully call the library in an executable. I'm not sure what's different on Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared library `libtest.so` that you have placed
in `/usr/local/lib` will be located by linker in the
command

```
gcc test.c -ltest
```

because `/usr/local/lib` is one the linker's default search
paths.

However, it will *not* be located there by the runtime loader
when you attempt to run `./a.out` because the runtime
loader does not search directories directly other than
those listed in the value of the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, if any,
in the current environment. By default it searchs the libraries
registered in the [`ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)
cache, and that cache is updated to register newly appeared libraries
only by running `ldconfig` (as root).

So to run your program you have two options:-

For success in your current shell, run:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib; ./a.out
```

For lasting success, run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then your program will run in any shell.

BTW, `ldd /path/to/libtest.so` tells you, of course, the
shared library dependencies of `libtest.so`. That's not
going to tell you why running `./a.out` fails to
find `/path/to/libtest.so` itself. To see the shared library dependencies
of `a.out`, run `ldd a.out`

Comment: I would recommend setting the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) at link time with `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`

Comment: @Mike Kinghan Doh....! I completely brain farted that I was using ldd on the library rather than the executable. For some reason, that threw me completely off. Appreciate the insight!